Filter People in ComboBox Based on Items in Gallery in Power Apps
I am building a Power Apps screen with the following setup:

A ComboBox (cmb) to display people from the User field in the SharePoint list Tasks.
A Gallery (Final) connected to the Tasks list, showing 3 items, each representing a different User.

Objective:
I want to filter the ComboBox (cmb) to display only the people currently shown in the Final gallery, rather than all the people associated with my account.
Implementation Details:
OnVisible of the Screen:
ClearCollect(
    UserCollection,
    ForAll(
        Tasks,
        If(
            !IsBlank(User),
            User
        )
    )
)

Items of the ComboBox:
Filter(
    Choices([@Tasks].'User'),
    DisplayName in ForAll(
        UserCollection,
        ThisRecord.DisplayName
    )
)

Issues Encountered:

ForAll: The function 'ForAll' has some invalid arguments.
DisplayName: Name isn't valid. 'DisplayName' isn't recognized.
UserCollection: Incompatible type. We can't evaluate your formula because of a type error.

Expected Behavior:
The ComboBox should show only the people currently appearing in the Gallery (Final).
Actual Behavior:
The ComboBox filters all people connected with my account, not just the ones visible in the Gallery.
Question:
How can I correctly filter the ComboBox (cmb) to show only the User values currently displayed in the Gallery?

The items parameter of your Gallery should the original datasource, not a Choice() function, and you should filter it. Like:
Filter(
Tasks,
User.Email = ComboBox1.Selected.User.Email)


So i follow your Solution and this show : 'This rule creates a circular reference between properties, which is not allowed. A property cannot reference itself or other properties affected by its value'
(field User is Multiple selections ! )
thank for your Answer bro <3
